# Type 'GFEventType' has no member 'KeyEntered'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, geofire

I have a GeoFire query that has been working for quite a while.  Suddenly when I go to update my podfile to the new firebase specs, it is now giving be the following error: Type 'GFEventType' has no member 'KeyEntered' on all of my queries that use KeyEntered.

Below is an example of one of the queries I'm running.

```
circleQuery.observeEventType(.KeyEntered, withBlock: { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in

        if key == self.ref.authData.uid{

            print("Found myself! Omitted.")

        }else{

            self.userKeys.append(key)
            self.userLocations.append(location)

            print(self.userKeys)
            print(self.userLocations)

        }

    }) //End userQuery
```

I'm afraid I've seriously messed up my GeoFire installation, how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't added many relevant details to help understand what's happening. A code sample would help, as well as details regarding what version of GeoFire you're upgrading from/to. Anyway, it looks like GeoFire made some minor updates to the `GFEventType` enumeration recently. Looking over the commit (it's brief) might help: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc/commit/c671ac98138e0f5e2b9e4f513a4c4b2443db2b25

Comment: Just added an example of my query, it's worked all the way up until about 30 minutes ago, when I was making some changes to the podfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `GFEventTypeKeyEntered`. Perhaps for some reason the automatic conversion of the enum failed.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, it just gives me the same error.

Comment: Just `GFEventTypeKeyEntered`, not `.KeyEntered` or `GFEventType.KeyEntered`

Comment: Just to clarify, in my initial reply to this I had tried to use .GFEventTypeKeyEntered, the period in front is what had me all mixed up.

Comment: The dot prefix makes the compile infer the enumeration type from the function signature. So that would be equivalent to `CFEventType.CFEventTypeKeyEntered`, which won't worj